# What does $ mean in a Scala Play Template, and how to deal with Options

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

First off, what exactly does `$` mean in the Scala Play Template engine?

Second off, I am trying to deal with an type Option in my Scala Play template, and it seems what I am doing should be rather simple. Here is a snippet of code from my template.

```
@c = { Some(complication) } 
<div id="complication">
@Html( (@c.name getOrElse "") ) `  
</div>
```

Where complication is of type `Option[T]`. The `name` field is of type string.

I've tried extracting it in to a another variable and then referencing the name field from that, but that seems so obtuse, there has to be a better solution it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `$` I think you may be referring to Scala's string interpolation.

Say you have `val str: String = "hello"`, then `s"$str world"` is equivalent to `str + " world"`

You don't need the `@` symbol inside `@Html`.

```
@Html( (c.name.getOrElse("")))
```